# Datatable Child Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to recreate [demo](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html)

My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfbeezhg/1/)

Frontend Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0
    }],
    order: [1, 'asc']
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For unknown reason, the details row does not appear (neither does the +/- signs on the left most column)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RacilHilan the example i have provided (official documentation) doesn't explicitly set details row either. It just uses the last td

Comment: Why don't you start by copying the entire demo as is, make sure it works, and then start modifying it? You are missing some CSS and JavaScript references (the responsive ones). Add them and you'll get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Problems:

1. You are not using the right libraries
2. You are using the responsive extension that hides automatically data based on the width. So you have to add more columns so the data overflows.

See the the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfbeezhg/6/).

```
Look at the used external resources to see the correct libraries to import.
```